# Unable to stop the test, @events.test_stop.add_listener locust

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I am unable to stop the test, if failure percentage or avg response time goes above the defined in test_stop.
Below is the sample code:-

```
@events.test_stop.add_listener
def results(environment, **kw):
    if environment.stats.total.fail_ratio > 0.01:
        logging.error("Test failed due to failure ratio > 1%")
        environment.process_exit_code = 1
    elif environment.stats.total.avg_response_time > 2:
        logging.error("Test failed due to average response time ratio > 200 ms")
        environment.process_exit_code = 1
    elif environment.stats.total.get_response_time_percentile(0.95) > 8:
        logging.error("Test failed due to 95th percentil response time > 800 ms")
        environment.process_exit_code = 1
    else:
        environment.process_exit_code = 0
     


    @task
    def osp_pick(self):
        return super().request(
            name="pick",
            json_file="data/pick.json",
            ssm=self.ssm,
            my_task=self,
           
        )


class StockTransfer(HttpUser):
    host = "https://zz-zz.dev.zz.zz.zz.com"  # Change this
    tasks = [Handler]
```

I am using below command to run the test from terminal:-

```
locust -f --headless -u 1000 -r 100 --run-time 2m
```

Command is working as expected, test is running for 2 min, but test does not fails if error percentage is > 0.01 or of average response time is > 2 sec

Comment: Have you verified your function changing the exit code is getting run? I'd start there, maybe replacing your `if` checks to be just changing the exit code. Then from there print out the checks and/or the stats you care about, making sure your units and everything match.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at locust-plugins's `--check-fail-ratio` for a battle tested way to achieve this:

https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins#command-line-options

Or, if you want to run the check *during* the actual test and interrupt it when it fails, you can use a background greenlet:

```
def checker(environment):
    while not environment.runner.state in [STATE_STOPPING, STATE_STOPPED, STATE_CLEANUP]:
        time.sleep(1)
        if environment.runner.stats.total.fail_ratio > 0.2:
            logging.info(f"fail ratio was {environment.runner.stats.total.fail_ratio}, quitting")
            environment.process_exit_code = 2
            environment.runner.quit()
            return


@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs):
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, WorkerRunner):
        gevent.spawn(checker, environment)
```